# howto fling the Gallery as normal when having custom view with ImageView and CheckBox

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-custom-view

I have an `android.widget.Gallery` with `ImageView` and a `Checkbox` on each Item.
The user can mark images for deletion.

I Cannot scroll/fling when i have this custom `View`.
Everything is loading fine and a see the images having the `CheckBox` ontop.

I understand that the touch event is not propagated down to the `Gallery`
How can i do that i read 20 discussions about this delegating touch but nothing works.

Heres my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/thumbImage" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
               android:clickable="false"
               android:focusable="false"
               />

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:clickable="false"
              />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has use for this i just figured this out myself.

Inside the `getView()` by removing `theimageview.setOnClickListener`